# List ou Datatable desktop c#

Tags: c#

Tenho uma aplicação utilizado camadas e tenho uma dúvida...

Quando a camada UI solicita vários registros, o que seria melhor carregar todo dentro de uma list<> ou utilizar o datatable?

Hoje meu utilizo da seguinte forma:

```
public List<ClienteModel> Listagem(string filtro)
{
    try
    {
        AbrirConexao();
        if (filtro == "")
        {
            Cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Clientes INNER JOIN Estados ON Clientes.id_uf = Estados.Id", Con);
        }
        else
        {
            //Usando Filtro - A Implementar
        }
        Dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<ClienteModel> lista = new List<ClienteModel>();
        while (Dr.Read())
        {
            ClienteModel c = new ClienteModel();
            c.Id = Convert.ToInt32(Dr["id"]);
            c.CodigoCliente = Convert.ToInt32(Dr["codcli"]);
            c.Nome = Convert.ToString(Dr["nome"]);
            c.Endereco = Convert.ToString(Dr["endereco"]);
            c.NumeroEndereco = Convert.ToString(Dr["nr"]);
            c.Bairro = Convert.ToString(Dr["bairro"]);
            c.Cidade = Convert.ToString(Dr["cidade"]);
            c.Cep = Convert.ToString(Dr["cep"]);
            c.Estado.id = Convert.ToInt32(Dr["id_uf"]); 
            c.Estado.sigla = Convert.ToString(Dr["sigla"]);
            c.Observacoes = Convert.ToString(Dr["obs"]);
            lista.Add(c);
        }
        return lista;
    }   
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Erro na Listagem dos Clientes.. " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        FecharConexao();
    }
}
```

Comment: que tal você perguntar qual a diferença entre os dois ? "o que seria melhor" se encaixa em uma pergunta baseada em opinião o que e fora do escopo do site entende ? posso postar um exemplo mostrando as duas formas e você pode comparar e definir qual e melhor para seu caso , mas o legal e você retirar sua pergunta do formato baseado em opiniões ,ela pode ser negativa ou fechada >.<

Comment: Sem contexto não tem como responder. Ambas podem ser bem ruins dependo do uso.

Comment: Editei o post.. Estava no Celular e não tinha o código.. é mais uma questão de o que seria melhor mesmo..

Answer (score 1):

Mesmo com a edição ainda ficou bem ambíguo sua ideia de "melhor", vou citar alguns pontos interessantes que pode acabar abrangendo sua dúvida.

Pensando em desempenho, bastante pessoas dizem que o List tem um desempenho melhor que o DataTable, e já que o objetivo é simplesmente envia-la para a UI, a classe List da conta do recado sem maiores problemas.

Outra coisa que vale a pena citar, existe um conceito na área da Orientação a Objetos chamado de SOLID, o quinto e último desses conceitos fala de Dependency Inversion Principle, nesse principio é comentado que você não deve usar implementação, e sim abstração no seu código. Você poderia utilizar um IList para armazenar esses valores.

Perceba que o IList recebe o ICollection e IEnumerable, você pode usar também um dos dois caso julgue necessário.

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

Entendido isso, você pode usar o método .ToList() ou qualquer outro método de conversão para transformar em uma coleção de objeto:

```
IList<ClienteModel> lista = new IList<ClienteModel>;
            while (Dr.Read())
            {
                ClienteModel c = new ClienteModel();
                c.Id = Convert.ToInt32(Dr["id"]);
                c.CodigoCliente = Convert.ToInt32(Dr["codcli"]);
                c.Nome = Convert.ToString(Dr["nome"]);
                c.Endereco = Convert.ToString(Dr["endereco"]);
                c.NumeroEndereco = Convert.ToString(Dr["nr"]);
                c.Bairro = Convert.ToString(Dr["bairro"]);
                c.Cidade = Convert.ToString(Dr["cidade"]);
                c.Cep = Convert.ToString(Dr["cep"]);
                c.Estado.id = Convert.ToInt32(Dr["id_uf"]);
                c.Estado.sigla = Convert.ToString(Dr["sigla"]);
                c.Observacoes = Convert.ToString(Dr["obs"]);
                lista.Add(c);
            }
            return lista.ToList();
```

Espero ter respondido sua dúvida.